# How to connect to Cisco firewall using hyper terminal

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I have bought the old Cisco PIX firewall 525. I connected the console cable into the firewall and serial port to my Window 7 PC. However when I start hyper terminal on `com1` my cursor keeps blinking and nothing happens. There is also USB port at the back of firewall.

Is there any other way to connect? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What does the manual for this router say on the subject?

Comment: Have you tried any others aside from com1? Did you check that your usb serial is on com1? Does the manual say that there is a specific management port?

Comment: Do you have the correct COM settings? Bits per Second: 9600- Data Bits:8- Parity:None- Stop Bits:1- Flow Control: none. What happens when you hit enter?

Comment: @Pretzel, i checked via device manager and it says COM1. what  other port i can try beside com1. there is only one serial port in my MB and hyper terminal is showing that only

Comment: @xxl3ww when i hit enter blank cursor moves forward , nothing happens. all com settings are correct as per cisco. this is the old one an dused one. is that can be the case

Comment: You may want to open it and see if memory is installed. If the device does not have memory, the fans will still function, but the device will not

Comment: There is no management ethernet interface on the back?

Comment: @Pretzel its like this http://www.nesevo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/i/pix-525-fo-bun-rear.jpg.jpg

Comment: @user19340357 Have you tried putty, or typing any commands at all to enable? I've had some cisco devices which responded in the same way, but if I enabled the device it became active.

Comment: @Pretzel putty says unable to open serial port

Comment: @user19340357, try changing com1 to 2...or 3..4..5 before establishing in putty.

Comment: @Pretzel where can i chnage the com1 to 2, in device manager there is only com1. also this is the cable i am using http://www.wti.com/images/Product/medium/236.jpg

Comment: I know the cable, I meant in Putty, not device manager. When you try to open a com connection in putty you can change the port from just com1. In device manager, you can change the com port in the device properties.

Comment: Were you able to check the RAM?

Comment: @Pretzel i treid com3 in both deviceM and putty but it says unable to open serial port

Comment: @xxl3ww actually i can't open it right now but it looks unlikey for RAM to be removed as it has  extra network interface card as well. but i can look at it in morning. as this was GOVT dept auction

Comment: @xxl3ww i ahve just checked there are 2 RAM stciks in there